# Django: sending data between applications

Tags: python, django, email, django-templates

I have an application named choix that contains e-mail field (will be sent to mail application as the e-mail of the recepient) integer field that contains time value (will be sent to another application aps  to its template as the frequency of showing graph) my goal is to send data by Database that I created in choix views but it returned an error:NameError: global name 'form' is not defined  .I guess my syntax is not correct at all 
choix/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from choix.forms import ConfigurationForm
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect


def index(request):
    if request.method == 'GET' :
        form = ConfigurationForm()
    else:
        form = ConfigurationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            e_mail = form.e_mail.data['e_mail']
            temps = form.temps.data['temps']
            temperature = form.temperature.data['temperature']
            post = m.Post.objects.create(e_mail=e_mail,
                                                         temps=temps, temperature = temperature)
            post.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('post_detail', kwargs={'post_id' : post.id}), 'index.html', form=form, f=temps)


    return render(request, 'configuration.html',  {'form': form})
```

mail/views.py

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail, BadHeaderError
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from choix import views 


def index(request):
    subject = request.POST.get('subject', 'subject')
    message = request.POST.get('message', 'attention ! la temperature a depasse le maximum ')
    from_email = request.POST.get('from_email', '***********@gmail.com')
    post = m.Post.objects.create(e_mail=e_mail)
    post.save()
    to = form.e_mail.data
    if subject and message and from_email:
        try:
            send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [ to ])
            return HttpResponse('templates/mail.html')
        except BadHeaderError:
            return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
        return HttpResponseRedirect('mail')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Make sure all fields are entered and valid.')
```

aps/views.html

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rasp import foo
from choix import views 

import json 

def index(request):
  return render(request, 'index.html', {'t' : foo(), 'form':form, 'f':temps})
```

Comment: What does "it didn't work" mean? What error did you see?

Comment: NameError: global name 'form' is not defined

Comment: Yes. You have not defined what `form` is. You should do that.

Comment: when I import choix.views it doesn't understand it ??

Comment: No. Why would you think that it would?

Comment: because I defined it in choix/views and I thought when I import it means like generalisation

Comment: No, absolutely not. Even leaving aside your misunderstanding of imports, if you had that `index()` view in the choix.views module, it *still would not work* for exactly the same reason; you need to define what `form` is in your function before you use it.

Comment: thank you your answer was really helpful